# BigQuery: Quotas - Query usage per day per user

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I want to see the **Current usage percentage** of **Query usage per day per user** in IAM&Admins/Quotas but I got an pop-up: `Per-user quota usage is not displayed.`

[image: screen-shoot]

How could I get the very details of this quotas, please? Or is it possible?

Thank you guys !!!

Comment: You can't see the quota per user, if it's your request.

Answer (score 0):

The feature to see the  current usage for **Query usage per day per user** quota in the Cloud Console Quotas page is not available at this moment for which a Pop-up  is shown i.e **Per-user quota usage is not displayed**.

The BigQuery team is aware of this issue and  a  feature request has been created for this issue. You can track the update on this request from this [link](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/175237776).

We cannot provide an ETA at this moment but you can follow the progress in the issue tracker and you can ‘STAR’ the issue to receive automatic updates and give it traction by referring to this [link](https://developers.google.com/issue-tracker/guides/subscribe#starring_an_issue).